# ¿Cómo sumar valores repetidos en una misma clave Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual el usuario tiene que agregar 1 clave (En este caso seria "*localidad*") y 2 valores a esta "localidad". El problema es que cuando el usuario pone una "*localidad*" ya existente se deberían sumar sus respectivos 2 *valores* a los *valores* anteriores

```
pregunta = "s"

estadisticas = {}

while pregunta == "s":

    localidad = input("Ingrese localidad: ")

    personas = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de personas que pueden trabajar: "))

    empleados = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados: "))

    if localidad in estadisticas:
        estadisticas[localidad] += personas, empleados
    else:
        estadisticas[localidad] = personas, empleados

    pregunta = input("Desea seguir ingresando?(s/n): ")

print(estadisticas)
```

Esto es lo que pasa:

```
 {'San': (2, 2, 2, 2), 'Bos': (2, 2)}
```

Esto es lo que quiero:

```
{'San': (4, 4), 'Bos': (2, 2)}
```

¿Alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias de ante-mano

Comment: ¿Las `personas` y `empleados` tienen que estar almacenados en tuplas o la estructura te es indiferente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes añadirle el valor que ya tenías almacenado a `personas` y `empleados`:

```
if localidad in estadisticas:
    personas += estadisticas[localidad][0]
    empleados += estadisticas[localidad][1]
    estadisticas[localidad] = personas, empleados
else:
    estadisticas[localidad] = personas, empleados
```

Esto te daría `{'San': (4, 4), 'Bos': (2, 2)}`

Si quieres, con diccionarios en vez de tuplas también lo podrías hacer:

```
if localidad in estadisticas:
    estadisticas[localidad]['personas'] += personas
    estadisticas[localidad]['empleados'] += empleados
else:
    estadisticas[localidad] = {'personas': personas, 'empleados': empleados}
```

Esto te daría:

`{'San': {'personas': 4, 'empleados': 4}, 'Bos': {'personas': 2, 'empleados': 2}}`

Otra cosa que debes tener en cuenta es si quieres que si el usuario introduce 'san', 'San', 'SAN' etc. las trate como iguales.

En ese caso deberías utilizar `input("Ingrese localidad: ").lower()` o similar.

Answer (score 2):

En tu caso, al hacer:

```
estadisticas[localidad] += personas, empleados
```

---

estás suponiendo una suma elemento a elemento de `estadisticas[localidad]` con `personas, empleados`, pero éste no es el funcionamiento de la suma de tuplas sino que en realidad el `+` funciona como concatenación. Por ejemplo:

```
print((2,3) + (2, 1))
(2, 3, 2, 1)
```

---

Para hacer lo que buscas, tienes algunas alternativas:

La forma clásica, accediendo por índice a cada elemento de las tuplas para sumarlos:

```
estadisticas[localidad] =  estadisticas[localidad][0] + personas,  estadisticas[localidad][1] + empleados
```

---

O también usar una comprensión de listas, para iterar y sumar cada pareja de elementos de las dos tuplas:

```
estadisticas[localidad] = tuple(a + b for a, b in zip(estadisticas[localidad], (personas, empleados)))
```

---

Agrego un muy completa pregunta dónde puedes encontrar otras interesantes alternativas para resolver el problema básico: [Python element-wise tuple operations like sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497885/python-element-wise-tuple-operations-like-sum)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que estas agregando campos. Y lo que buscas es modificar esos campos.
Te sugiero cambiar el if por esto

```
if localidad in estadisticas:
    estadisticas[localidad][0] += personas
    estadisticas[localidad][1] += empleados
else:
    estadisticas[localidad] = [personas, empleados]
```

también es importante que utilices arrays `"[]"` o diccionarios `"{}"` en vez de tuplas "()" ya que las tuplas no pueden modificarse por dentro, que es lo que te sucede en el resultado.

```
diccionario = {"nro1": 1,"nro2": 2}
array = [1,2]
tupla = (1,2)
```